# Visor/editor para ficheros de texto para intercambio de datos tipo Contaplus y exportaciones a contabilidad, etc

Tags: estructuras-de-datos, txt, procesamiento-de-texto, visualización-de-datos

Me gustaría saber si alguien conoce de alguna aplicación, ya sea descargable (preferible en Linux) u online, y si es gratuita mejor, que te permita visionar e incluso editar ficheros de texto para intercambio de datos, con posiciones asignadas en cada línea, como sucede en las exportaciones de programas contables tipo Contaplus, donde cada dato tiene una posición determinada en la línea y un número asignado de caracteres.

Si además, dispusiera de plantillas de determinados programas contables populares como Contaplus, A3, etc, o poder preconfigurarlas, para un mejor visionado de los datos, mucho mejor.

Comment: Tu pregunta probablemente termine [cerrada](/help/closed-questions) por solicitar recomendaciones de librerías o recursos externos.

Comment: Vaya, no sabía que no era posible hacer este tipo de preguntas. Gracias por decirlo.